# Is there a way to match ID video and ID post with Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to gather reaction count, share count, comments, duration and view count of every video posted on my Facebook account. I use :

- `https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me/videos` to get the comments, duration and view count
- `https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/me/posts` to get reaction count and share count.

Each call returns an ID. However, I get the video ID with `me/videos` and the post ID with `me/posts` which differ from one another even if they are linked to the same video. I do not manage to find a key to match them. Is there a way to find the post ID from `me/videos` or the video ID form `me/posts`? Or is there another way to make them match?

Comment: `attachments` field of the post should contain the reference to the video. The opposite connection does not exists AFAIK, because there could be multiple posts made sharing the same video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `attachments` field of the post should contain the reference to the video.

The opposite connection does not exists AFAIK, because there could be multiple posts made sharing the same video.